# Delay functions in Google spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets, import, google-sheets-formula

Spreadsheet stuck at loading when loading many `importxml` requests.

I have a spreadsheet that pulls names and prices from a website, about 40 requests per link. Everything works fine until I try importing from more than one link at a time. Is there a way to make the spreadsheet only load a certain amount of requests at one time? Also update it only once every hour. I found [a script](https://qr.ae/pyjAlr) that creates a new function that uses `regex` to bypass the limit, but since I'm a noob and don't know how `regex` works and have a hard time finding usefull info, I would like only adding a delay for requests.

[The spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aPQ8ztiCgeSu9QVasnxakI7cmejE2rf3H39MkXtGJuE/edit?usp=sharing). To use the spreadsheet you have to make a copy.

I also only want the `steam` and `buff163` prices, but since the website changes based on price sorting, I import everything and pull only the prices I need, very ineffective, I know. If you have any help regarding this, it solves basically everything.